# Use multiple phones when developing for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android

My droid works fine. The other two droids I've tried are never recognized by adb and don't debug. Debugging is turned on with all 3 of them.

What's the problem?

Comment: when you plugin you have to probably change from Charge only mode to Sync mode

Answer (score 1):

To test that you have the correct drivers installed (on windows) or have everything setup right (on os x or linux):

- Open a command prompt/terminal
- Navigate to the tools folder of the android sdk
- run "adb devices" (no quotes)
- If all is well it will list all the device names on a new line. If something is wrong with your setup you will see question marks a line

I'm guessing you've seen this already but if not take a look at [the instructions](http://d.android.com/guide/developing/device.html) for setting up a devices for development.

Just as a side note, I'm not sure you can have 3 of the exact same device working at the same time (I assume you meant you have 3 Droids). Might only work with 3 distinctly different devices.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to enable debugging in the phone settings ?
(in  Settings => Applications => Development )

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by droid? Motorola Droid, HTC Droid or are you using droid to just mean you have three different models of android phone?

If the latter there is some configuration necessary - for my HTC Desire I had to setup some drivers: http://myhtcdesire.com/tutorials/how-to-install-the-adb-driver-on-windows